# Combining two lists with different elements to one list with all elements and SAME index in c#

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I have two different lists **geocode1** and **geocode2** both of 5 rows of records.
**geocode1** has 4 columns namely address, city, zip and street.
**geocode2** has 4 columns namely latitute, longitude,Status and County

Merging them using addrange like below:

```
 geocode1.Addrange(geocode2)
```

results in geocode1 with 8 columns( which is what I desire) but of 10 rows, with first five containing the values in first list (geocode1) and last five with values from 2nd list (geocode2). (like outer join in SQL)

I desire to have 8 columns but 5 rows with the elements of both lists combined like a inner join does in SQL. Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Comment: I researched for the answer, and used "addrange" or "cocat' which do not solve my problem.

Comment: @YvetteColomb oh.. it can have so many reasons. I was wondering about the reason of down votes for some of my questions/answers but no down voter cared to mention. I was wondering about the reason here as well, but your link clarified it. Sorry gutsy_guy to clutter your thread, but indeed it would help everybody.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: When I used the addrange, I used the debugger to check the values in the list (I am not displaying it), there were 8 rows. First 5 rows contained the values that were in 1st list, but the elements in 2nd list were empty. Then in last 5 rows,only  the values of the elements(columns) of 2nd list only displayed, the columns of first list is null.
It's funny how a question is asked by a low reputation user is suddenly deemed lack of research.

Comment: @PM.: It is ok , since I was checking the values with the debugger and did not display the list anywhere, it was not possible for me to "show" my research unless I write a separate code to display. Anyway, I got my answer and use of ZIP solved my problem thanks to Willy. Another fact is some people here are really keen to down-vote  the users having low reputation immediately. "Prejudice" is a common human nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need zip for that:

```
var result = geocode1.Zip(geocode2, (c1, c2) => new ModelName
         {
           Address = c1.Address,
           City = c1.City,
           Zip = c1.Zip
           Street. c1.Street,
           Latitute = c2.Latitude
           Longitude = c2.Longitude,
           Status = c2.Status,
           Country = c2.Country
         }).ToList();
```

Make sure both list have the same number of length since Zip will follow the shortest list.